# Arcgis address locator issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, address, geocoding

I have an issue with creating an address locator on ArcGIS 10.2.2.
I always used an address locator somebody else made, it's made on ArcGIS 9.2. When I look into its properties, it says

> Description: US Streets, Style: N/A

.
The thing is I made a locator by my own, using the US address dual range style, which I think it's the same as the previous locator. I use all the required fields.

But the new locator takes forever to complete the job, and most of the times it ends up crashing, whereas the old locator keeps working smoothly.

Anybody has a clue on why this could be happening?

SOLVED:

I ran into this explanation:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2010/10/29/haunted-by-geocoding-brew-up-something-new-with-9-3-1-locator-styles-in-10/

So I downloaded the locator styles from 9.3 and followed the instructions to add them.
Then I created a 9.3 style locator, and it worked as a charm. I guess it's a 10.2.2 bug.

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the sample size to see if you get the same non result?

Comment: Do you want to answer your own question or should I just close it? (We need to do something otherwise the thread will always remain in the system as unanswered.)

Comment: Sorry, my idea was to answer my own question, I just thought that was the way.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

I ran into this explanation: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2010/10/29/haunted-by-geocoding-brew-up-something-new-with-9-3-1-locator-styles-in-10/

So I downloaded the locator styles from 9.3 and followed the instructions to add them. Then I created a 9.3 style locator, and it worked as a charm. I guess it's a 10.2.2 bug.

Thank you all